# Can't get image to draw in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, monogame

Ive build a animation image in photoshop with 12 frames/images in it. So im trying to make this draw function to go through the first 4 images in file. The width of the picture is in pixel 1340. So actually there is a new frame in each 340 pixels in the first row. There are 3 rows. The whole image resolution is 1330x1998. So If I write

```
new Rectangle(_animationFrame * 0, 0, 3100, 3900)
```

So Now its showing the first picture from all of the pictures. So if I increment by one that
animationFrame its not going to next picture. aargh what im failing here?

EDIT:

I got it working like this

```
int[] x = { 0, -780, -1560, -2332 };


protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)        {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        _spriteBatch.Begin();
_spriteBatch.Draw(_radarTexture, new Rectangle(x[i], 0, 3100, 3900), Color.White);
        _spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Update function will increment value in x array to go through frames.
It is ridiculously wasting of time, when your trying to test right scale and x/y coordinates to get it right. There must be easier way but cant get it...

EDIT 2
Okay I think I get it. Photoshop showed as centimeters, not pixels the coordinate when I clicked options open. Thanks all for helping out. I will mark the first answer as right because now in this case it is the right answer. Thank you

Comment: What do you think is the result of multiplying any number by zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you wanted to do was:

```
new Rectangle(_animationFrame * 340, ...)
```

since "there is a new frame in each 340 pixels" as you wrote.
What you're doing now, as the comment says, is multiplying a number by 0, and that's useless.

**EDIT**

What I understand is that you want to draw the first 4 images of your spritesheet, each one havig a *width* of 340. Their *height* I suppose to be 1998/3, because you have 3 rows in your spritesheet.
So, here's your code (`_animationFrame` starts from 0):

```
new Rectangle(_animationFrame * 340, 0, 430, 1998 / 3);
_animationFrame++;
if (_animationFrame == 4)
  _animationFrame = 0;
```

Comment: Could yo be more precise in practical meaning what int x, int y, width, height does?

Comment: So ive tried and this what happened. When I used width: 430 and heigth 1998 / 3 it zoomed out the whole picture, so I was able to see the whole image file and being moved left to rigth pretty fast. And when I used width:3100 and heigth: 3900 it zoomed in to first frame of first row. And when animationFrame got + 1, it looked like the whole image just when half of it to right. Outside of phone actually. Ive uploaded the picture here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/2eGxNQe.jpg) so you can see it for youself what im trying. Exact resolution is 1330x1998 .

Comment: Interesting. I made x coordinate value to -780 and it did show 100% of the next picture. It's just strange that its negative value not positive as my book told me, and I need to try different values to got it exact right. hmm

Comment: If you want to animate a sprite you need to change the texture to draw every draw cycle (or slower if you want), but you have to draw only a part of the whole spritesheet to animate it correctly. In your case you have 12 frames, so you have to draw a Rectangle having dimensions (1330/4, 1998/3). Of course that Rectangle is the `Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle` parameter of your draw.

Comment: Hmm okay, but Ive got it right after killing nerves and trying 50 times I got these values int[] x = { 0, -780, -1560, -2332 }; So x[3] = -2332 is outside of the whole resolution. It doesnt make any sense

Comment: It is interesting when I've made 800x200 picture and put 4 different frames in it and new Rectangle(animationFrames 200, 0, 800/4, 200) wont work. It just shows background color but no picture..